# Dúvida Python 3 Selecionando itens de um dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite a todos, tudo bem? Sou novo em Python e estava fazendo alguns exercícios onde precisava selecionar algumas informações de uma base de dados. Em um dos subitens,  o código correto era:

```
halftime_musicians[halftime_musicians.super_bowl <= 27]
```

No seguinte, o código correto era:

```
# Display musicians with more than one halftime show appearance
halftime_appearances[haltime_appearances['super_bowl'] <=2** ]
```

Porque no primeiro caso, para fazer referencia a uma coluna da Super bowl eu usei a `coluna.super_bowl` e no segundo caso tive que usar `coluna['super_bowl']` ao invés de `coluna.super_bowl`?

Answer (score 0):

É a 'mesma coisa'. Você tem as duas possibilidades pra acessar as mesmas coisas. O autor do exercício quis te mostrar que você pode fazer de uma forma ou de outra que o resultado será o mesmo.

Isso:

```
halftime_musicians[halftime_musicians.super_bowl <= 27]
```

Equivale a isso:

```
halftime_musicians[halftime_musicians['super_bowl'] <= 27]
```

Este é um atributo do dataframe: `halftime_musicians.super_bowl`, ele só vai passar a 'existir' depois que a coluna 'super_bowl' for criada.

Já com a notação `df['coluna'] = 1` você consegue criar e atribuir um valor sem ela existir. E ai depois ela ficara disponível em `df.coluna` ou `df['coluna']`.

Comment: Apenas adicionando algo útil ao tópico, uma outra opção, e até mais recomendada é utilizar a função query, desta forma (por exemplo): halftime_musicians.query('super_bowl <= 27')